# How to check os version in rpmbuild spec file

Tags: linux, rpm

I am building an rpm where I need to check the OS version. If it is rhel5 or rhel6, then it'll work, else it'll stop.
Please advice how can I make it.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:DistTag is this helpful ?

Comment: may be this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9296/how-can-i-specify-os-conditional-build-requirements-in-an-rpm-spec-file

Comment: I am building rpm on Centos 5 and the following is not working:
%if 0%{?rhel} == 5
Any idea, please.

Answer (score 1):

There's %{rhel} you can check

```
$ rpmbuild --eval %{rhel}
7
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9296/how-can-i-specify-os-conditional-build-requirements-in-an-rpm-spec-file
however this only decide what go inside of package in buildtime. And you can still install el6 package on el5 and vice versa.

So if you want to do decide that during actual installation, the you need to parse /etc/os-release (IIRC exist only in el7+) or /etc/redhat-release.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternate Use to use the `uname` command and parse Information

Save time execute the following:

```
uname -r | cut -d '.' -f6
```

This is valid in RHEL 6 and 7.

Comment: Your answer should be reworded. It is not very clear.  Please read SO guidelines before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @YangXiao's answer:

```
%if 0%{rhel} >= 7
  do something
%endif
```

The 0 is necessary in case %{rhel} is empty because the macro will fail to evaluate as invalid syntax.

Answer (score -1):

You can run `cat /etc/issue` and parse as necessary

Comment: /etc/issue (at least on my systems) has replaceable parameters.  i don't think you can reliably determine the OS version using this file