# cpack restrict OS version package can be installed on

Tags: centos, redhat, rpm, rpmbuild, cpack

I create packages for several OS versions including RHEL7 & RHEL8 (or mostly equally CentOS7 & 8).

It is possible to install a package built for .el7. on .el8. but it will typically not work (for example due to undefined symbols etc).
Ideally I would like to make the installation fail with an error message like "this package is only intend for RHEL7/CentOS7".

How can I do this?
More specifically how can I do this with CPack/CMake?

Bonus points if you can also given an explanation suitable for Debian versions.

---

Here are some ideas I have so far:

1. Use [dist tags](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/DistTag/) somehow, see:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/283330/rpm-spec-conditional-require-based-of-distro-version

2. Check `uname -r` at install time in a pre-install script
   Part of that answer is here:

- [How to check os version in rpmbuild spec file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931356/how-to-check-os-version-in-rpmbuild-spec-file)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9296/how-can-i-specify-os-conditional-build-requirements-in-an-rpm-spec-file

I'm not quite sure how to do that using cpack. I do not want to generate a custom spec file as the build machinery is already complex enough.

3. Another option would be to add a %requires on a package that only exists on RHEL7 but not RHEL8 or visa versa. That package would need to also exist on CentOS and not change in a way that would make the installation fail if it is upgraded. Does anyone know a suitable package to depend on?

For example:

```
>rpm -q --whatprovides /etc/redhat-release 
centos-release-8.2-2.2004.0.1.el8.x86_64
```

This looks like a good candidate but if I add a dependency on centos-release-8.2 and they later upgrade to centos-release-8.3 or use RedHat instead this will not work.

Comment: The easiest way is to do **nothing** :) Do not make things complicated. Your package name should contain smth like `<name>-<version>-el7.x86_64.rpm`  (or `*.el8.*`) -- that is a sign to the user about the target distro (same rules for Debian/Ubuntu). If he installs the package to the wrong distro it is **not your problem**! :) Whatever you gonna do, if the user wants to install smth that is not targeted for his distro **he'll find a way** to shot his leg
If you have a repo for your stuff, just put the packages to different dirs and ask users to configure their `/etc/yum.repos.d/*` properly.

Comment: While it is true that whatever you do someone will find a way to be a better class of idiot I believe its better for problems to scream loudly and early rather than subtley.

Answer (score 0):

I [did this before](https://github.com/opencpi/opencpi/blob/master/packaging/driver.spec#L81) by having a stanza in `%pre` that stopped it:

```
if [ -n "%{dist}" ]; then
  PKG_VER=`echo %{dist} | perl -ne '/el(\d)/ && print $1'`
  THIS_VER=`perl -ne '/release (\d)/ && print $1' /etc/redhat-release`
  if [ -n "${PKG_VER}" -a -n "${THIS_VER}" ]; then
    if [ ${PKG_VER} -ne ${THIS_VER} ]; then
      for i in `seq 20`; do echo ""; done
      echo "WARNING: This RPM is for CentOS${PKG_VER}, but you seem to be running CentOS${THIS_VER}" >&2
      echo "You might want to uninstall these RPMs immediately and get the CentOS${THIS_VER} version." >&2
      for i in `seq 5`; do echo "" >&2; done
    fi
  fi
fi
```

Remember - you *cannot* have any user interaction in RPM installation. You could have it fail instead of warn tho; that's up to you.

Comment: This is potentially half the answer but the question was how do you do this with cmake/cpack.