# How to write message to screen after installing a RPM?

Tags: rpmbuild

I'm building RPM packages and I want to output a message to the console after installing the package. In this message, there are some pointers for the person who is installing the package.

Can someone show me how to do this in the spec file?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean with **the console**...

You can print some message in the `%post` or even `%posttrans` section. This output will be shown on the console when the user installs your package using `rpm`, `yum`, `dnf`, `zypper` or similar on the command line. When the user uses any graphical interface, he won't see that message (or not easily).

If you want to decide in which section to print your message and under what conditions, [this](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/) is a great resource on the scriptlet order and their arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can write to `STDERR` (there's an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63865972/836748)). *However*, client interaction upon installation is pretty much impossible *by design*. For example, if your RPMs were added to a Kickstart script for an automated installation, the output would never be seen.

A much better paradigm is to do what they do for things like Apache where they drop in a default configuration (easily done with symlinks in your `%post`) that present some kind of sample interface with "additional configuration is required..."